# Updating a ChangeNotifierProvider's value on "componentDidMount"

Tags: flutter

I am passing values down my widget hierarchy using `Provider`. There is one scenario where I must update the value from a descendent widget either before the widget is drawn, while it is being drawn, or even shortly after it is drawn, something similar to React's `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook.

Is this possible? It seems like you need the `BuildContext` object, which is appears to only be available inside of a widget's `build` method.

To showcase the problem I have this code sample (beware: it throws exceptions):

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var attrs = Provider.of<SelectedPageAttributes>(context);
    attrs.updateSelectedPageAttributes(title, color);

    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            middle: attrs.title != null
                ? Text(attrs.title, style: categoryPageTitle)
                : null),
        child: Container(
            child: SafeArea(child: child),
            )));
  }
```

Essentially, I am trying to update the widget before returning it. This rightfully complains that `setState()` is being called during build, but I do not know where else to call it. Are there any lifecycle hooks I can use?

Please note that I understand one can use `Provider<T>` to send data downstream, but this seems inconvenient since it has to be reapplied whenever there is a new page route, whereas using a `ChangeNotifierProvider` avoids this when it wraps the app.

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://www.filledstacks.com/post/flutter-architecture-my-provider-implementation-guide specifically the `onModelReady` section. I use `onModelReady` to do anything before the view builds.

Comment: @MattList got a 404 error

Comment: Weird, the URL works fine for me. If you go to FilledStacks.com and look for the Provider Architecture Implementation Guide.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `componentDidMount` in Flutter.

Your best bet will be to use `initState` and schedule a callback that will be executed after the frame ends:

```dart
initState() {
  super.initState();
  Future.microtask(() {
    Provider.of<Foo>(context).doSomething();
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to schedule the callback before the frame ends?

Comment: When do you want it to be called?

Comment: Is there a hook to call it before anything else gets rendered/painted in that given widget?